# Reporting machine resolution as experimental error

Tags: error-analysis

I'm doing a measurement with a machine that has a resolution of $0.14 \mu\textrm{m}$. I can do said measurement many times and then calculate the average of measurements, which comes to $52.0094 \mu\textrm{m}$, with a standard deviation smaller than the resolution limit.

Can I report my value as $52.01\pm 0.14 \mu\textrm{m}$ or should I round the average to one significant value in the decimal position? Or would it be better to report the full uncertainty?

Comment: How many measurements? What's the standard deviation? A histogram of the measurements would help.

Comment: The detector picks up 4 decimals but the resolution I mentioned comes from the stage. I have 10 measurements and their average come to 52.00940 and the standard deviation is equal to 0.004286.

Comment: Can you give more details about the experiment? What are you measuring? What is your procedure? What is your readout device? How many digits of precision can the device readout compared to the stated resolution of 0.14 um? Also where does 0.14 um come from? Is that from a datasheet for some part or something else? And like JEB asks, can we see a histogram of data from repeated measurements?

Comment: In some cases you can realize sensitivity better than the stated resolution of the device but it depends on exactly how you're performing the measurement.

Comment: You need to retain units for clarity: so $\sigma = 4.2\,$nm from a device with 0.1 nm quantization...but some other implementation detail has 140 nm resolution? Is the latter Gaussian, uniform, or something else? Uniform is usually from quantization, which has $\sigma = 1/\sqrt{12}$ times the quantization size. We really need to know more about that set-up, but eventually you may want $52.0 \pm xx^{\rm stat} \pm 0.4^{\rm sys}\,\mu$m.

Comment: @JEB why ascribe 0.4 um to systematic not statistical? I would think that was statistical.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple situations:

1. If the standard deviation for the individual measurements ($SD$) is large compared to the resolution $res$, we can neglect the resolution. The distribution of the $SD$ determines the standard error of the average value $SE$. In the example below I assume a normal distribution and $N=10$ measurements, such that $SE = SD/\sqrt{N}$.
2. If $SD \ll res$, we can neglect $SD$. Assuming that every value within the length defined by the resolution has the same probability, we obtain a uniform distribution. Thus, the measurement uncertainty becomes $SE = res/\sqrt{12}$.

In between these extrem cases the exact location of the true value matters, and the interplay between the two components ($SD$ and $res$) becomes complicated. This can be seen by simulation.

In the code I define SD such that the ratio SD/res ranges from $10^{-4}$ to $10$, because I want to get equi-distant points in the log-log plot:

```
set.seed(17983)

nRepeat = 2e3       # repeated experiments
nSim    = 10        # number of measurements for a single experiment
res     = 0.14      # resolution measurement device
mu      = runif(nRepeat, min=20, max=80)  # true population value (random, but fixed)

# Now we want to change the standard deviation of the individual measurments
nSD = 100                                # number of SD we simulate
SD  = res * 10^seq(-4, 1, length=nSD)    # standard dev. of measurement 
SE  = vector(mode="numeric", length=nSD) # allocate space 
for ( i in 1:nSD ){
    err       = rnorm(nSim*nRepeat, mean=0, sd=SD[[i]]) # random error
    dim(err)  = c(nRepeat, nSim)         # reshape: each row is a measurement
    data      = mu + err                 # add true value to each row (dirty programming)
    data      = round(data/res)*res      # round to resolution
    E         = mean.rowwise(data)
    Delta     = E - mu
    SE[i]     = sd(Delta) # standard error
}

# Generate a log-log plot:
plot(log10(SD/res), log10(SE))
lines(log10(SD/res), log10(SD/sqrt(nSim)), col='red') # normal distr.
abline(h=log10(res/sqrt(12)), col='blue') # standard deviation for a uniform distr.
```

which yields the following

[image]

To obtain an intuition for the region $SD \approx res$ we take two perspectives:

1. Starting with the normal distribution and decreasing $SD$ the finite resolution *increases* the probability density in the edges. Effectively this increases the standard deviation of the normal distribution. That's why the dots are above the red line.
2. Starting with the uniform distribution and increasing $SD$ we "loose" some probability density in the edges of the uniform distribution, because the normal distribution shifts this density to the center. We can think of this situations as obtaining a uniform distr. with a smaller width $res$. That's why the dots are below the blue line.